# Add/Inject Agent to Queue in Anylogic

Tags: java, queue, anylogic

I have a mixed model in Anylogic where some of my agents have to add Parts (which are also agents) to a Discrete Event Simulation QUEUE.

Getting agents from a QUEUE is done through `queue1.removeFirst();` but I can't seem to find the equivalent to add something.
I've tried `addAgentToContents` with no luck...

Answer (score 2):

You cannot add an agent to a queue directly.

Either you put a source object in front of it and set its "Arrival defiend by" property to "inject()". Also set its "New Agent" type to Part. When your agent wants to add a part to the queue, you'd call `source.inject()` and a part will be added to the queue.

Alternatively, if you have created the part agent already, you can use a port from your Agent and link it to your queue using a Connector. Both objects can be found in the "Agents" library.

hope this helps

Comment: Thanks Benjamin. I've been trying to establish the connection but I still have to "send" the Part somehow. There's the `send` method but it copes with messages only... do you know how to do this?

Comment: A message can be any type, not just a string. If you check the Javadoc for the method "send" for a Port, it will tell you that the parameter "msg" is of type "Object" which means it can be anything.

Comment: Ended up using an Enter process block to "send" the Part agent back to the process chart

Comment: that is the third option I forgot to mention... There are always several ways to achieve something in AnyLogic and it often depends on your existing structure.

Comment: @jacandau how did you connect agent with queue? i used connector to connect agent and queue which results in this error "Exception during discrete event execution: root.queue.input: InPort can only be connected to an OutPort"